# convert vbulletin database into wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, vbulletin

I've been considering converting my vbulletin forum to a wordpress blog but it doesn't look like its a simple process. I've googled around for a convertor but nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WP + BBPress`. Do a search for BBPress import from vBulletin and see what you can find. There should be BBPress plugins for that, but, since I'm not vBulletin user, can't really help more.